# DELETE a record in relational position in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, relational

I am trying to clean up records stored in a MySQL table.  If a row contains `%X%`, I need to delete that row and the row immediately below it, regardless of content. E.g. (sorry if the table is insulting anyone's intelligence):

```
| 1 | leave alone 
| 2 | Contains %X% - Delete
| 3 | This row should also be deleted
| 4 | leave alone
| 5 | Contains %X% - Delete
| 6 | This row should also be deleted
| 7 | leave alone
```

Is there a way to do this using only a couple of queries? Or am I going to have to execute a SELECT query first (using the `%x%` search parameter) then loop through those results and execute a DELETE...WHERE for each index returned + 1

Comment: @Aiias: That's a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

This should work although its a bit clunky (might want to check the LIKE argument as it uses pattern matching (see comments)
        DELETE FROM `table`.`db` 
    WHERE `idcol` IN 
    ( SELECT `idcol` FROM `db`.`table` WHERE `col` LIKE '%X%') 
    OR idcol`IN 
    ( SELECT`idcol`+1 FROM`db`.`table`WHERE`col` LIKE '%X%')

Comment: This relies on not gaps in the ids.

Comment: LIKE doesn't use regexes, REGEXP does; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the table was named `test` and contained to columns named `id` and `data`.

We start with a SELECT that gives us the id of all rows that have a preceding row (highest id of all ids lower than id of our current row):

```
SELECT t1.id FROM test t1
  JOIN test t2 ON
    ( t2.id, true )
      =
    ( SELECT t3.id, t3.data LIKE '%X%' FROM test t3
        WHERE t3.id < t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

That gives us the ids 3 and 6. Their preceding rows 2 and 5 contain `%X%`, so that's good.

Now lets get the ids of the rows that contain `%X%` and combine them with the previous ones, via UNION:

```
(SELECT t1.id FROM test t1
  JOIN test t2 ON
    ( t2.id, true )
      =
    ( SELECT t3.id, t3.data LIKE '%X%' FROM test t3
        WHERE t3.id < t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )
)
UNION
(
  SELECT id FROM test WHERE data LIKE '%X%'
)
```

That gives us 3, 6, 2, 5 - nice!

Now, we can't delete from a table and select from the same table in MySQL - so lets use a temporary table, store our ids that are to be deleted in there, and then read from that temporary table to delete from our original table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE deleteids (id INT);

INSERT INTO deleteids
  (SELECT t1.id FROM test t1
    JOIN test t2 ON
      ( t2.id, true )
        =
      ( SELECT t3.id, t3.data LIKE '%X%' FROM test t3
          WHERE t3.id < t1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT id FROM test WHERE data LIKE '%X%'
  );

  DELETE FROM test WHERE id in (SELECT * FROM deleteids);
```

... and we are left with the ids 1, 4 and 7 in our `test` table!

(And since the previous rows are selected using <, ORDER BY and LIMIT, this also works if the ids are not continuous.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in a single `DELETE` statement:

Assuming the "row immediately after" is based on the order of your INT-based ID column, you can use MySQL variables to assign row numbers which accounts for gaps in your IDs:

```
DELETE a FROM tbl a
JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, b.id AS nextid
    FROM (
        SELECT     a.id, a.text, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rownum 
        FROM       tbl a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=1) rn_init
        ORDER BY   a.id
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT     a.id, @rn2:=@rn2+1 AS rownum 
        FROM       tbl a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2:=0) rn_init
        ORDER BY   a.id
    ) b ON a.rownum = b.rownum
    WHERE a.text LIKE '%X%'
) b ON a.id IN (b.id, b.nextid)
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo (added additional data for example)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9d43/1/0)

---

What this does is it first takes your data and ranks it based on your ID column, then we do an offset `LEFT JOIN` on an almost identical result set except that the rank column is behind by `1`. This gets the rows and their immediate "next" rows side by side so that we can pull both of their id's at the same time in the parent `DELETE` statement:

```
SELECT a.id, a.text, b.id AS nextid, b.text AS nexttext
FROM (
    SELECT     a.id, a.text, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rownum 
    FROM       tbl a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=1) rn_init
    ORDER BY   a.id
) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT     a.id, a.text, @rn2:=@rn2+1 AS rownum 
    FROM       tbl a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2:=0) rn_init
    ORDER BY   a.id
) b ON a.rownum = b.rownum
WHERE a.text LIKE '%X%'
```

Yields:

```
ID     | TEXT                   | NEXTID   | NEXTTEXT
2      | Contains %X% - Delete  | 3        | This row should also be deleted
5      | Contains %X% - Delete  | 6        | This row should also be deleted
257    | Contains %X% - Delete  | 3434     | This row should also be deleted
4000   | Contains %X% - Delete  | 4005     | Contains %X% - Delete
4005   | Contains %X% - Delete  | 6000     | Contains %X% - Delete
6000   | Contains %X% - Delete  | 6534     | This row should also be deleted
```

We then `JOIN`-`DELETE` that entire statement on the condition that it deletes rows whose IDs are either the "subselected" `ID` or `NEXTID`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reasonable way of doing this in a single query. (It may be *possible*, but the query you end up having to use will be unreasonably complex, and will almost certainly not be portable to other SQL engines.)

Use the SELECT-then-DELETE approach you described in your question.